# Unable to programatically select elements on browser's New Tab page

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, chromium

I'm in the latest version of Edge, but this also applies to Chromium.

When I open a new tab, I get the content at ntp.msn.com (news, ads, etc). I can inspect any element and see it on the Elements tab of DevTools, but I can't select any of them using javascript in the Console, e.g.:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[area-label=Reddit]')
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('cs-native-ad-card') // non standard tag?
```

both return a nodelist of zero length. Why/how is this page different from any other?

Comment: For me, on Edge, nearly everything is under a `#shadow-root`. You can't bridge over these boundaries via `.querySelectorAll`. Instead, you'd need to get the element with the shadow root, get the shadow root's content from `.shadowRoot`, then find the next element with a shadow root, and repeat. (And this only works with open shadow roots. Closed roots are usually only accessible by the code that created them.)

Comment: See [Using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), [Using shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), and [`ShadowRoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot)